# find ... -exec command not executing on all files found

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, find

How come this command:

```
find . -name \*.css -o -name \*.php -type f
```

gives me a list of all the *.css and *.php files BUT adding the 'exec' option:

```
find . -name \*.css -o -name \*.php -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

only changes the file permissions of the `*.php` files and not the `*.css` ?

NOTE: I am using Amazon EC2 Linux.

Comment: thank you for helping me mark up the code text, I am still learning how do properly post questions here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You misunderstand the AND / OR actions.

```
find . \( -name \*.css -o -name \*.php \) -type f -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

find tries to find out whether an expression is true or false. If the left side of an OR is already true then it is not necessary to execute the right side. Your approach would work if OR had higher priority than AND but that is not the case.